# Jquery function binding

Tags: jquery, function, bind

Can I get a couple of good examples on how to bind 3 separate functions I've got going on?

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more explicit. What are you binding them to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one function that calls all three and then bind to that function.

Or use an anonymous function:

```
$("#MyItemID").bind("click", function(){
  func1();
  func2();
  func3();
});
```

You can also use the shorthand event. So (e.g.) for click:

```
$("#MyItemID").click(function(){
  func1();
  func2();
  func3();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just chain them:

$("#MyItemID").click(func1).click(func2).click(func3);